# Alternative of OffsetByXY method of mapXtreme in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, mapxtreme

I have an application in MapXtreme. I am converting that into PostGIS.For a purpose I am using the below given function in Mapxtreme.

```
IGeometryEdit geomEdit = ftrgeo.GetGeometryEditor();
geomEdit .OffsetByXY(-(Convert.ToDouble(300) / 2), -(Convert.ToDouble(300) / 2), DistanceUnit.Foot, DistanceType.Spherical);
geomEdit .EditingComplete();
```

What are the alternative methods of above in PostGIS?

Any Idea?

Comment: What does this function do, move things north west by 300 feet? Come on, you can ask a better question that doesn't presuppose expertise in mapxtreme and postgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding exactly what this function does, I think you want [ST_Translate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html)

> Returns a new geometry whose coordinates are translated delta x,delta y,delta z units. Units are based on the units defined in spatial reference (SRID) for this geometry.

```
ST_Translate — Translate a geometry by given offsets.

Synopsis
geometry ST_Translate(geometry g1, float deltax, float deltay);
geometry ST_Translate(geometry g1, float deltax, float deltay, float deltaz);
```